# React Checkbox Controlled Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is driving me crazy. I have no problem with select drop downs and text fields, but for some reason, I cannot get checkboxes working in a controlled fashion. That it is I want them to 'toggle' and listen to this event in a parent component.

I understand there is a 'checked' property for inputs of type checkbox. Selecting a checkbox gives it a value of 'on'. I take this 'on' value and convert it to true or false, and update the component accordingly.

For some reason, I cannot get this to work, either it is always selected, or it is never selected (if I switch the boolean switch).

```
export class ControlledCheckbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      select: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.info("this.state.select - " + this.state.select);

    let sel = false;

    if (this.state.select !== "on") {
      sel = true;
    } else {
      sel = false;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={sel}
          onChange={this.handleChangeCheckbox}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChangeCheckbox = (e) => {
    console.info("here e.currentTarget.value " + e.currentTarget.value);

    this.setState({
      select: e.currentTarget.value,
    });
    //call passed through callback here
  };
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-tereshkova-tcdq9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 5):

`value` [serves a different purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value) for `checkbox` inputs and you should not use it to define your state's value. You need to take a look at the `e.currentTarget.checked` instead.

```js
export class ControlledCheckbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      select: false,
    }
  }

  handleChangeCheckbox = e => {
    this.setState({
      select: e.currentTarget.checked // <--
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.select}
          onChange={this.handleChangeCheckbox} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you are working with multiple inputs (not only checkboxes) you can follow the approach suggested by [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs), where you can cover multiple input types with only one `setState`. Keep in mind to define a `name` in this case, so you can separate your inputs:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
          name="hasValue"
          checked={this.state.select}
          onChange={this.handleChangeCheckbox} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about *controlled* inputs, however your checkbox isn't controlled yet. You rely on the value stored inside checkbox, not inside the state.

```
this.setState({
   select: e.currentTarget.value, // here
});
```

Use a `value` that comes from the state instead.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
   select: !prevState.select,
}));
```

**Note**: You can remove the conditions from the *render*, they are redundant.